# How to fix this condition?

Tags: python, datetime, conditional-statements

```
def do_something():
     print("Do Something !")
def do_nothing():
     print("Do Nothing !")
day=datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%A")
time=datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")
start_time=int(time.split(":")[0])
end_time=int(time.split(":")[1])
## Monday Conditions
if day.lower()=="monday" and start_time==9 and end_time>10:
    do_nothing()
elif day.lower()=="monday" and start_time==9 and end_time>41:
    do_something()
```

on monday, i want to run correct conditions on time but even on correct time, this condition runs all the time:

```
if day.lower()=="monday" and start_time==9 and end_time>10:
    do_nothing()
```

im new to python

Comment: A few recommendations for cleaner code: rather than using `strftime("%A").lower() == 'monday'` I'd recommend to use `datetime.now().get_weekday()` which returns `0` for Monday. Similarly with the time: use `datetime.now().hour` to get the "hour" value, for minutes value use: `datetime.now().minute`

Comment: try set timezone

Comment: yes..it will run why because if some random number is greater than 41 then it also greater than 10...so your elif condition never gets executed

Comment: The problem is because, for example, end time is 15, then the first if condition is in play, and assume that end time is 50, then still the first if condition is in play. because 15, 50 >10

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to run a piece of code on a particular day and time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try switching `41` and `10` in the if statements:

```
if day.lower()=="monday" and start_time==9 and end_time>41:
    do_nothing()
elif day.lower()=="monday" and start_time==9 and end_time>10:
    do_something()
```

Comment: you forgot to swap between `do_nothing()` and `do_something()` in order to get the same logic.

also explain why you use this logic and don't give him a peach

Comment: @Ido no problem :)

Comment: @AbhimanyuSharma this comment was belong to Joep not to you.

Comment: @Ido Thanks, you're right :). Was thinking about an edit but you already explained perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

let assume `end_time = 50` so always `end_time > 10` and `end_time > 41`

you can do this

```
if day.lower() == "monday" and start_time == 9 and end_time > 41:
    do_something()
elif day.lower() == "monday" and start_time == 9 and end_time > 10:
    do_nothing()
```